# Weird data bytes order in STM32F303 SPI on receiving

Tags: stm32, spi, fifo

I can't understand the things that are going when I'm trying to read SPI data by STM32F303. On my scope I see next sequence: 0x9c, 0, 0, 0. But I receive them in differend order.
Here is my read function:

```
volatile uint32_t wctr;
#define WAITX(x)  do{wctr = 0; while((x) && (++wctr < 360000)) IWDG->KR = IWDG_REFRESH; if(wctr==360000){ DBG("timeout"); return 0;}}while(0)

int spi_read(uint8_t *data, uint32_t n){
    if(spi_status != SPI_READY){
        DBG("not ready");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!spi_waitbsy()) return 0;
    // clear SPI Rx FIFO
    (void) SPI2->DR;
    while(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) (void) SPI2->DR;
    for(uint32_t x = 0; x < n; ++x){
        WAITX(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
        SPIDR = 0;
        WAITX(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
        data[x] = SPIDR;
        USB_sendstr("rd got "); USB_sendstr(uhex2str(data[x]));
        newline();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And in terminal I got:

```
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x9c
Sregx10=0x9c000000
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x9c
rd got 0x00
Sregx10=0x9c0000
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x9c
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
Sregx10=0x9c00
rd got 0x9c
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
Sregx10=0x9c
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x00
rd got 0x9c
Sregx10=0x9c000000
```

It seems like some trash in Rx FIFO and cleaning doesn't help.
When I try to receive data over DMA, I have the same problem. And why always on first read I have first data byte at last place?

Here is reception using DMA:

```
Sregn9=8
00 00 00 fa 29 82 00 00
Sregn9=8
00 00 fa 29 82 00 00 00
Sregn9=8
00 fa 29 82 00 00 00 00
Sregn9=8
fa 29 82 00 00 00 00 00
```

The right data order is 0xfa, 0x29, 0x82, 0 (as I see on scope). But STM32 each time receives data in different way with 3, 2, 1 or 0 zeros before real data.

Is this a bug of this specific MCU, or something wrong with my code? How can I omit this variable amount of zeros before main data?

Comment: what exactly is `WAITX(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)); SPIDR = 0;`? Why TXE? And also `(void) SPI2->DR; while(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) (void) SPI2->DR;` the while never executes, because a read of DR immediately resets the RXNE. As an alternative, you could try to implement that by polling fifo threshold, if you wanna go blocking way. While FIFO threshold < 1/4, wait, when it is 1/4, a byte is received, read it. In general, it seems your waits are polling wrong flags and your loop executes quicker than you actually receive the data. Repetitive read to DR doesn't return the same value as per ref man

Comment: So it's very likely you get a byte, you read DR, then your loop fails to wait for the next byte to arrive and reads DR again, and repetitive read of DR returns 0x00 as per reference manual page 963 (doesn't specify 0x00, but it's possible). And this whole thing messes up the FIFO, because you read when there is already nothing in there, and it's hard to tell how it affects the peripheral. This is just a speculation, but it's the first thing that comes to mind. Try addressing it and see if it helps.

Comment: There is something I struggled with with QSPI, which was somewhat similar in effect: how exactly do you read DR? You're having volatile uint32_t DR. You read 4 bytes instead of 1. Every single read. It messed up my FIFO there as well. Try reading it as 'uint8_t newbyte =   \*(uint8_t\*)(&SPI->DR);', this helped me with QSPI. Alternative theory. Also pretty good one, given you actually read DR every time 4 bytes at a time

Comment: @Ilya: I see, that repetitive reads of DR almost always returns me the same data. The source of `WAITX` is in the upper string of code. I wait TXE to transmit next zero byte (to init SPI for next reception). As I say, DMA readings returns the same trash before main data. Macro `SPIDR` is reading/writing of `SPI2->DR` as `uint8_t`.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `while(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) (void) SPI2->DR;`? Why not empty while? This still looks very much like your loop loops faster than it receives data. Make a dummy global var and increment it every time you read a byte, for instance, experiment with it, increment it in different places, try to detect potential premature loop exit. DMA is out of the picture for now. If your blocking configuration doesn't work, don't bring in DMA, or at the very least post full DMA configuration and stuff. Still, one problem at a time. Let's solve blocking problem for now.

Comment: Personally, in situations like this, I almost always fully delete the first implementation and write another one from scratch. Second driver almost always works for me, because you already know what to expect (roughly), what flags you will need. Why not try implementing it via polling FIFO threshold level? Also, remove all the unnecessary garbage like newline() and USB-something functions. Just focus on one thing. You receive data, check the received bytes. Do nothing else. All other bells and whistles come later. Sometimes these bells and whistles are actually the cause.

Comment: @Ilya, While not empty while? I just want to read all FIFO, until RXNE disappears. And after that I hope, that FIFO is empty and I can start reading. But it isn't empty. When I try to change RXNE to shoot at half-buffer (not quater), than I miss one byte of data. But trash still goes on. I see true received data in scope window, and I see what I get by SPI...

Comment: If it weren't empty, you would be stuck in that while forever. So clearly it is empty at some point, since it actually goes past that while receives something.